# Alternative to Mysql NDBCLUSTER

Tags: mysql, cluster-computing

I need create a very big project, the project has a lot of tables and a big quantity data.
In first moment I thought to use NDBCLUSTER but I saw that not suport foreign keys and I have to use triggers, really I don't like this solution but I need that my database is replicated to other nodes.

Please if somebody know any solution for use foreigns key with mysql or other database manager and balance data I would love to know it.

Comment: I have the same problem. Hope someone can help us!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that MySQL Replication can be an alternative, even Apache Cassandra but now we will try to give it a try NDB Cluster and non-relational model

Answer (score 1):

There are a range of solutions you can look at - take a look at this whitepaper (note, registration needed) to get a summary:
http://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/white-papers/mysql_wp_ha_strategy_guide.php